# How to get workflow instance id in workflow association form?

Tags: workflow

I am working on SharePoint 2010 sequential workflow. I have added association form to workflow. I want to store Workflow Instance id to one list while associating workflow.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to get workflow instance id while association?
2. How to get workflow Instance id in Association form?

I have tried for `associationparams.instanceId` but its Guid is always 000...000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue. At workflow Activated, we can get the workflow instance id. So I am adding workflow instance id when workflow is getting activated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but i guess it will help others. I use SharePoint 2013 workflow

```
[%Workflow Context:Instance ID%]
```

To navigate to workflow status, use

```
/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List=[%Workflow Context:List ID%]&WorkflowInstanceName=[%Workflow Context:Instance ID%]
```